# Why is an inline edit adding a new row? 

Tags: jqgrid

In inline mode I add a new row, Edit new value, then click the 'save' button to server and local. However, when I continue to click the 'edit' button to edit the new row instead of editing the row it adds a new one. For example, first I add a new row : `{ aa,bb,cc}`, then  want to change it to `{ aaaa,bb,cc}` by clicking the 'edit' button and editing it, but jqGrid sends an `oper=add` to the server, this leads to an add new row. I don't understand why?

code as follow:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ddddd</title>
<link
href="/education2/jqGrid4.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css"
rel="Stylesheet" />
<link href="/education2/jqGrid4.4/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script src="/education2/jqGrid4.4/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/education2/jqGrid4.4/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/education2/jqGrid4.4/js/i18n/grid.locale-cn.js"></script>

<script src="/education2/jqGrid4.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid({
        url : '/education2/json/searchStudent',
        mtype : "POST",
        datatype : "json",
        colNames : [ 'studentId','studentNo', 'name', 'class'],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'studentId',
            index : 'studentId',
            width : 55,
            hidden : true,
            hidedlg : true
            key : true,
            editable : true
        }, {
            name : 'studentNo',
            index : 'studentNo',
            width : 150,
            editable : true         
        }, {
            name : 'studentName',
            index : 'studentName',
            width : 150,
            align : "right",
            editable : true
        }, {
            name : 'className',
            index : 'className',
            width : 150,
            align : "right",
            editable : true,
            edittype : 'select',
            editoptions : {
                dataUrl : "/education2/json/classNameStudent"
            }   
        }],
        jsonReader : {
            root : "gridModel",
            records : "record",
            repeatitems : false
        },
        prmNames : {
            search : "search",
            id : "id" 
        },
        rowNum : 10,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        height : 400,
        //          multiselect : true,
        //          multiboxonly : true,
        pager : jQuery('#gridPager'),
        sortname : 'studentId',
        viewrecords : true,
        altRows : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        editurl : "/education2/json/editStudent",
        caption : "student"
    });

    jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid('navGrid', "#gridPager", {
        edit : false,
        add : false,
        del : true
    }, {}, {}, {}, {
        caption : "find",
        Find : "find",
        closeAfterSearch : true
    });

    jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#gridPager", {

        editParams : {
            successfunc : succesfunc1,
            restoreAfterError : false
        }
    });
});

var succesfunc1 = function(response) {
    var result = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
    if (result.success == true) {
        alert("success!");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(result.message);
        return false;
    }
};


};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="gridTable"></table>
<div id="gridPager"></div>
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I use `$('#'+$.jgrid.jpID(rowid).attr('id', result1.new_id)` to refresh row id of the new row (idea from @oleg in question "how to update column after inline add in jqGrid"), and on the server I use `oper=new && id !="new_row"` to decide if it should be an edit or add a new row. It runs well, but I must add an aftersavefunc method.

The question above isn't well understood by me. What I do is only bypass the question.

My problem is that I: add a new row then change it, jqgrid doesn't change it, jqgrid sends an `"oper=add"` to server, this means the server will add a new row.

Another question is:

```
jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#gridPager", {

    addParams : {
        addRowParams : {
            keys : true,
            url : '/education2/json/editStudent1?inlinePoer=add'
        }
    },
    editParams : {
        url : '/education2/json/editStudent?inlinePoer=edit',
    }
});
```

Unlike I expect, whenever I click add, edit or the save button in inline navigator, only the url : `'/education2/json/editStudent?inlinePoer=edit'` is fired. It seems url : `'/education2/json/editStudent1?inlinePoer=add'` cannot be fired, why? Could somebody help me?

I use firebug, and IE.

Comment: Are you editing the column that is the row key(StudentId)?

Comment: yes, i edit and save the data to server

Comment: So if your editing your key, you are creating a new record. If you instead do not declare a key on your grid column it will use autogenerated rownumbers as the key which may solve your problem.

Comment: thank for your help. the studentId is autogenerated rownumbers ,and studentId is set to key in jqgrid.  jqgrid can't get new studentId from server(i don't know what should return from server),so after i saved the new row , the row id of the new row is set to "new_row",not the new studentId  returned to jqgrid from server by form of  {"className":"dfd","id":"55","message":"success!","new_id":55,"studentId":55,"studentName":"fefef","studentNo":"fefe","success":true}

Comment: my problem is that : add new row then change it ,jqgrid don't change it , jqgrid send a "oper=add" to server, this means server will add a new row. so i think jqgrid canot get correct return value from server ,so can not set row id of new row. is i wrong?

Comment: Thanks for coming to StackOverflow for help. It is good to see that you have edited additional details into your question, however I would refrain from the re-posting of this question multiple times as that could result in a ban. Also when you have an answer marked as accepted, the majority of users are not going to help as you are giving them the indication that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing is giving edit:true in following line

```
jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#gridPager", {

        editParams : {
            successfunc : succesfunc1,
            restoreAfterError : false
        }
    });
```

check this link

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav and look at the parameters here. I'm not sure about it just try to give edit as true, if it works fine, great...else i'll look into your code when i'll be done with my office work.

Comment: thank your help ,but add edit:true is unuseful. 

and i find out that id of the added row is  "new_row", but i think it will be a int value of studentId,  

data from server is {"id":"28","message":"success!","new_id":28,"success":true},maybe this return value is not standard return of jqgrid?  could somebody help me ?  thank you !

Comment: well i can assure u this that row id of jqgrid row and student id will never be the same.

Comment: and jqgrid website give us only what should be sent to server ,but i can't find out what data should return from server.  where can i find document about  what data should return from server about jqgrid? thank you !

Comment: can i change the row id of jqgrid row ?

Comment: I;m sure your problem is not so difficult, but what you really want to do, i can't understand that.

Comment: when i add new row ,the row id is set to "new_id", then when i add a new row again ,it also is set to "new_id", this may bring problem,because the two row id is the same . so ,i think when i add a new row , save it , then the row id of the new row shouldn't be "new_id" and should be value of studentId because i set 'studentId' key : true. so one of fowllow may be true:

Comment: one :   jqgrid auto set the row id of row ,not  "new_id".  two :jqgrid set the row id according the return value from server

Comment: buddy when your grid will be refreshed then that new_id wont be new id, It will get some row id according to number of rows in your grid

Comment: my problem is that :  add new row then change it ,jqgrid don't change it , jqgrid send  a "oper=add" to server, this means server will add a new row.

Comment: but the grid don't set the row id with number of rows, unless i click refresh button in  the grid inline pane

Comment: what do u want to send to server?? studentid or row id of jqgrid? obviously studentid, right? and when u add a new row with a new record, lets say student id=9, student no=55, class=blah, name=blah then the data which will be sent to server will be this only, and lets just assume u had 20 records in ur grid and this was 21st so untill ur grid is not refreshed ur row id will be "new_row", once it is refreshed your row id for that record will become 21. get it?

Comment: man u need to add  reloadAfterSubmit:true in ur add parameters.

Comment: my problem is that : add new row then change it ,jqgrid don't change it , jqgrid send a "oper=add" to server, this means server will add a new row.  so i think jqgrid canot get correct return value from server ,so can not set row id of new row.  is i wrong?

Comment: you can not set the row id of jqgrid, if u r thinking to set student id as your row id then forget about it. why do u want to do that anyway? reloading the grid after add operation will anyhow give a row id to your record

Comment: Piyush Sardana  you are right . when i refresh ,the row id be set to sutdentid. but if i add a new row ,then change it ,this lead wrong. maybe this is a bug?  if in order to change it ,i must refresh ,this is not a good experience. do you think so ?

Comment: and in form model ,there is not this problem,  i think that form model and inline mode  can be same technology .

Comment: dear piyush sardana: i try as follows: 
    jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#gridPager", {
      addParams : {
          addRowParams : {
                url : '/education2/json/editStudent?inlinePoer=add',
                 }
          },
     editParams : {
            url : '/education2/json/editStudent?inlinePoer=edit'
                 successfunc : succesfunc1              }
     });
 but all url sent to server is '/education2/json/editStudent?inlinePoer=edit'. whatever i click add, edit, save button in inline panel, is there syntax error or this method can't solve my problem?